# C++, std::copy and templates

Tags: c++, templates, vector, copy

I am doing experiments with templates and STL. This is my testing code...

```
template <typename Item>
struct TList
{
    typedef std::vector <Item> Type;
};

template <typename Item>
class Cont
{
private:
    typename TList <Item>::Type elements;

public:
    void push_back ( const Item & p ) {elements.push_back ( p );}

    typename TList <Item>::Type ::iterator
        copy (typename TList <Item>::Type ::iterator first,
                typename TList <Item>::Type ::iterator last,
                typename TList <Item>::Type ::iterator result) 
        {
            elements.resize(elements.size() + last - first);  //Exception
            return copy ( first, last, result ); 
        }

        typename TList <Item>::Type ::iterator begin() { return elements.begin(); }
};
```

But during a copy operation

```
int main()
{
    Cont <double> cont;
    cont.push_back(1);
    cont.push_back(2);

    TList <double>::Type v;
    v.push_back(3);
    v.push_back(4);
    cont.copy(v.begin(), v.end(), cont.begin());  //Exception
    cont.copy(v.begin(), v.end(), cont.end());  //Exception

    return 0;
}
```

the program causes a runtime exception. Could you help me to find the error?

```
Exception: Vector iterator + offset out of range...
```

Comment: -1: Have you tried stepping through your code in a debugger?  Or adding trace statements to determine the values of key variables?

Comment: This is seriously dangerous code you have there. What is it for?

Comment: @Space: Only test in my learning of c++...

Comment: Once again I see a downvote on a question without a comment. If you downvote something, leave a comment. This isn't rocket science.

Comment: @oli: Good, now I can ask why you think it should be -1'd. :) Seems like a reasonable question to me.

Comment: @GMan: I almost always downvote questions that follow the pattern of "Here is my code.  It does not work.  Why not?" with no apparent attempt to debug it.

Comment: @Oli: This question doesn't fit that pattern. It's: "Here's what I was doing, here's what I tried to do with it, here's the error I unexpectedly got, I can't figure out why I'm getting it, can you help?" Has pretty much everything we ask for in a question.

Comment: @Oli, I debug the code before sending, but I can not think of a trick with parentheses...

Comment: @GMan: Then I guess we'll have to disagree!  I agree that the OP has explained *what* the error is (which is often lacking), but there's a step missing: an explanation of what debugging was attempted (e.g. stripping the code down, printing intermediate variables, etc.).  That's the only viable approach to fixing these things (assuming you don't happen to spot the error by inspection).

Comment: @Johnas: Sorry if my downvote seemed harsh, I don't mean it personally!  It's just that there are a lot of questions that follow this pattern here on SO, and the answer is usually the same: strip your code down to the minimum possible *before* posting a question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The expression:

```
elements.size() + last - first
```

is evaluated as:

```
(elements.size() + last) - first
```

The result of the first addition will be an iterator that exceeds the vector's bounds, which triggers the exception (in debug mode).  You could try this:

```
elements.size() + (last - first)
```

Or the more STL-like approach:

```
elements.size() + std::distance(first, last)
```

Comment: Thanks, but there is another problem: return copy ( first, last, result ) results in stack overflow. Why?

Comment: @Johnas:  That line calls *your* `copy` method, so you end up with an infinite recursion.  You will need to explicitly state which function you want, i.e. `return std::copy(first, last, result)`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is caused by the fact that your `copy` method resizes the vector, thereby making the iterator you passed it invalid.

Comment: I don't think that's the issue here.  If the OP's code snippet is to be believed, the exception occurs on the line that performs the `resize`.

Comment: @Oli: I just realized that too. I will leave the answer though, because it would happen if the new range is larger than the old one.